# Change Date Format with Perl

Tags: mysql, perl, date, csv, format

I have a text file which I'm converting to a csv file with information that I want to import into a MySQL database.

I currently have the date in this format:

```
Mar 24
```

I would like to change that format

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

I would like to do this in perl as I have done all the other bit in the csv file in perl.

Comment: Would you just use this year if not given a year? Have you tried any code yet that you can post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tentative solution to your problem using [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece), which is a core module and shouldn't need installing.

I'm very unhappy about your input date format not containing a year. The code below assumes the current year, but I can imagine that a date like `Jan 3` should be upgraded to the following year if the code is run on 31 December.

The year has to be included in the string to be parsed because `Time::Piece` will alter `Feb 29` to `Mar 1` for non-leap years.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

print bd_to_ymd('Mar 24');

sub bd_to_ymd {
  my ($bd) = @_;
  my $year = localtime->year;
  my $tp = Time::Piece->strptime("$year $bd", '%Y %b %d');
  $tp->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
}
```

**output**

```
2014-03-24
```